# I'm an American citizen. I've lived/studied abroad for a couple of years. Do I need a visa to study in France?

Tags: education

I'm an American citizen. I've been studying and living abroad for a couple of years, and now I want to go to France to study. Would I need a visa? And does anyone know the procedure?

Comment: It depends mostly on the duration of your study, are you thinking about a full-time university programme? Anything longer than 3 months requires a visa or residence permit.

Answer (score 2):

Having been abroad in the past doesn't give you any special rights. If you want to go to France to study, you'll have to find a university or other place of education, apply, and, if you are accepted, [go through the visa procedures](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/venir-en-france/etudier-en-france/demarches-administratives/article/visas-etudiants) [in French]. Universities have an administrative office that helps foreign students do that. They'll have all the information you need.